# Annotate seaborn heatmap with asterisks

Tags: python, annotations, seaborn, heatmap

I created a heatmap with seaborn (see code below) and would like to annotate each cell with asterisks in case the correlation represented in the cell is significant. The asterisk information is stored in a separate CSV file; it has the same amount of rows and columns as the input file for the heatmap, each cell contains either an asterisk or "NaN" and I also tried leaving the NaN cells empty. I also tried leaving the same column names as in the input file in the asterisk file, and a version with no column names. However the error I get every time is

**"ValueError: Data supplied to "annot" must be the same shape as the data to plot.
Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes"**

Code for heatmap:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import seaborn as sns; 
            
    plt.figure()
    data = pd.read_csv('/Users/polo/Desktop/Input/Correl.csv')
    pvals = pd.read_csv('/Users/polo/Desktop/pval.csv')
    #pvals =  np.array([['*','*','*','*'],['*','***','*','*'],['***','*','*','*'],['*','*','*','*'],['*','*','*','*']]) #also tried this, same error
        
    hmap = sns.heatmap(data,cmap='seismic',linewidths=.5,vmin=-0.1, vmax=0.1, yticklabels=row_labels, annot=pvals)
    hmap.set_ylim(0, 5)
    hmap.set_title('Partial correlation')
```

Comment: Your two dataframes probably don't have the same number of rows or columns.  Are you using the latest seaborn version?  When I try to reproduce your problem, and add `fmt=''`, I obtain the expected plot.  Can you add some reproducible data? I tried `data = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(5, 4), columns=[*'ABCD'], index=[*'VWXYZ']);
pvals = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.choice(['', '*', '**', '***'], (5, 4)))`

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohanC, this helped me fix it! For anyone having a similar problem: Turns out pvals was not read properly and all columns were passed as one, so I changed line 8 to pvals = pd.read_csv('/Users/polo/Desktop/pval.csv',sep=';') -> Then still had to add fmt='' like you said and now it works. Now I just need to get rid of the "NaN" that got printed into empty cells, and unfortunately the heatmap is plotted inversely so my asterisk file doesn't match the order

Comment: The heatmap and the annotation use exactly the same order.  You must have saved them in the wrong order.  Use `annot=pvals[::-1]` to reverse the order of the rows.  You could replace `'NaN` with `''` in your dataframe.  It's hard to guess the exact way you are storing the values.  Adding reproducible data would help a lot.